# Formatting a 3rd-party .NET object in debugger

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, formatting

I'm working with a 3rd-party library that builds a [`NameObjectCollectionBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase%28VS.80%29.aspx)-derived map of name-object pairs. The collection is sometimes big (thousands of items) and I'd like to use the VS 2008 debugger to inspect items in it. (I'm not looking for a specific item in the map, I'm trying to see if the list of items looks like what I expect.) The map contains `NameObjectEntry` instances. When I inspect this map in the debugger, this is what I see:

```
[0] {System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.NameObjectEntry}
[1] {System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.NameObjectEntry}
...
[191] {System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.NameObjectEntry}
[192] {System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.NameObjectEntry}
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to tell the debugger how to format `NameObjectEntry` to show me the data inside an instance, not the type name. Something like:

```
[0] {"key1","value1"}
[1] {"key2","value2"}
...
[191] {"key191","value191"}
[192] {"key192","value192"}
```

With my own classes I could either override `ToString()` or use the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute but `NameObjectEntry` is part of the .NET framework, I can't change it. Unfortunately, search results mostly recommend one of these two.

Is there anything I can do to force the debugger to show this object in a specific way?

**Edit**: for future readers, the solution was to use the `autoexp.cs` file that comes with VS, as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419%28VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `DebuggerDisplay` attribute. It's easy when you have access to source code of the class. Check this link for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx.

If you don't have access to the source code, you can try to do the following:

- make sure you can create classed derived from the class you want to format in debugger
- create derived class in your own code (it can be just an empty class)
- apply the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute to the derived class and you this class in your application (instead of the external one)

So, let's say you have an external class named `SampleExternalClass`

In your own code, you should create a derived class:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("custom formatted object with string = { StringPropertyNameFromBaseClass } ")]
class SampleInternalClass : SampleExternalClass
{
    //you don't have to put anything in here
}
```

After those steps, when you use view object of `SampleInternalClass` type in your the debugger, it should be formatted as specified in the attribute.

This seems to work when both classes are in the same dll, but I suppose it should work in case of separate dlls as well.

Comment: How do I apply this attribute to a type I don't have the source for?

Comment: Hmmm, sorry, it seems I missed that it's 3rd party dll and I thought you have access to the source of the class. I'll look for another solution to work in your case.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it helps me: I don't create these objects, I get them from a 3rd-party library. I can create a derived class of the type in question but the 3rd-party library won't use my derived class - it'll use the original class.

Comment: You could convert objects to your class (build new objects) based on the original ones, but this will probably decrease overall app's performance. The solution I described is rather for debugging cases, when you want to detect bugs quickly and should be then removed from the code.

Comment: I'd like to avoid that - that's why I asked the question about telling the debugger to format the data on the fly. If I have to go through all that in a bunch of places, it doesn't really help me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can take a look here: http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=202 and here: http://code.google.com/p/linqpadvisualizer/, I haven't tested those, but maybe they'll work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. It's not exactly what I'm looking for but if I don't get any more (more helpful) answers, I'll mark yours as accepted because I really appreciate you trying to help.